# How to distribute a single column of data into two columns equally distributing data?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am displaying a table in html consisting of only a single column full name :

> ```
> Full_name
>   Alex
>   Frown
>   Chris
>   Dram
>   Drex
>   Pheobe
> ```

I have used a for loop in  to display the names. But i want the output to be displayed in two column distributed equally like:

```
Full_name      Full_name
  alex          Frown 
  Chris         Dram
  Drex          Pheobe
```

Comment: i tried distributing the list into two parts by dividing the names according to their odd or even id . But as the data can be deleted sometimes from between the list will not be equally divided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what i was trying to achieve could be simply done by css. Just give a css class to the tbody, in my case i named it `split-table` then add the following css:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .split-table tr{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
    .split-table tr:nth-child(1n+2){
      background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the names to two arrays, for example by index. If remainder of index divided by 2 is 0 push it to one array, otherwise push it to the other array.

```
let fullNamesArr...
let fullNamesLength = fullNamesArr.length;

let leftColumn = [];
let rightColumn = [];

for (let i = 0; i < fullNamesLength; i++) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    leftColumnt.push(fullNamesArr[i]);
  } else {
    rightColumn.push(fullNamesArr[i]);
  }
}
```

and then just display the two tables next to each other.

Or you can use styles.

1. Make a "*header*", with two divs with the same `width` (300px), both
   containing the string Full_name.
2. Make container with `width` for example `600px`. Give it a style of `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;`
3. In that container add the ngFor element and give it a 300px width.
   (600 and 300 is an example)